Cannot read type library file: '..\..\AuthAPI\Build\AuthAPIv24.tlb': Error loading type library/DLL
I'm using Visual Studio 2019. The line of code:
#import "..\..\AuthAPI\Build\AuthAPIv24.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only
The error:
Error   C1084   Cannot read type library file: '....\AuthAPI\Build\AuthAPIv24.tlb': Error loading type library/DLL.
Before this, this line of codes worked well. Not sure why now it doesnt work. Also, not sure if this affects it or not but I renamed my directory (from Work_Repo to Work_Repo_MY) and put that main folder (which consist of sln and everything in my project) to become a sub folder under a folder (MY_2024) to tidy up working space.

I tried copy the file path ("C:\Work_Repo\MY 2024\Work_Repo_MY\AuthAPI\Build\AuthAPIv24.tlb" and replace it directly:
Same error prompted out.
I tried put wrong directory in the code:
Error   C1083   Cannot open type library file: 'C:\Work_Repo\MY 2024\Work_Repo_MY\AuthAPI\Build\Test\Test\AuthAPIv24.tlb': No such file or directory
I tried make the tlb file as read only:
Same error still prompted out.
I tried make the tlb file not as read only:
Same error still prompted out.

So, I think this is not a case of the file path being incorrect as pointing to different path will show different error. If anyone can shed some light on how this tlb stuff even works or what this error might mean I would greatly appreciate it.

Open C:\Work_Repo in your file explorer, then search for the AuthAPIv24.tlb file. I can't determine the location of this file from your description. Record the path obtained from the search and place it after the #import statement for use.
